# Facing Error while running a JMeter script using docker file on AWS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, jmeter, performance-testing

Hi I am Niladri Shekhar De, relatively new to performance testing. I am trying to run my load test (scripted in JMeter) using docker file on AWS. I am editing the docker file as  mentioned in [docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYP5A.jpg) this picture. Also, I have edited the entrypoint as this
[entry point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itxsf.jpg) picture.  Then while I am trying to run it is waiting for long after "Waiting for possible shutdown...." line and finally I am getting all 10 errors (My script has 2 transactions and I am running for 5 users) as shown in the picture[cloudwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaszM.jpg). The script name may be mentioned here is different than in the docker file but that I have changed later. Could anyone please look into this and help me out? It will really be a great help..

Answer (score 0):

Although your way to take screenshots is fantastic you [should not be posting code as images on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Coming back to your question: we cannot see any failure reason there so I would suggest to check:

1. The [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), it should have status code, response message, maybe response details, etc.
2. The [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) which normally can give a clue regarding what's wrong. If it doesn't - you can try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)